# При отправке HTTP запроса (API), путь файла стал вида \320\220\320\272\321\202_\32

Tags: java, escape

Путь к файлу изначально: \catalog\share\file_01.03.2019_18.03.20198614743500721097370.xlsx
\320\220\320\272\321\202_\321\201\320\262\320\265\321\200\320\272\320\270_file_01.03.2019_18.03.20198614743500721097370.xlsx
                        
Необходимо отключить escaping? Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался давно и делюсь ответом. Все верно. В коде запроса путь прописан как UTF-8. Поэтому запрос имеет такой вид.